# Is there a problem with multicollinearity and for splines regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, multicollinearity, splines

When using natural (i.e. restricted) cubic splines, the basis functions created are highly collinear, and when used in a regression seem to produce very high VIF (variance inflation factor) statistics, signaling multicollinearity. When one is considering the case of a model for prediction purposes, is this an issue? It seems like it will always be the case because of the nature of the spline construction.

Here is an example in R:

```
library(caret)
library(Hmisc)
library(car)
data(GermanCredit)

spl_mat<-rcspline.eval(GermanCredit$Amount,  nk=5, inclx=TRUE) #natural cubic splines with 5 knots

class<-ifelse(GermanCredit$Class=='Bad',1,0) #binary target variable
dat<-data.frame(cbind(spl_mat,class))

cor(spl_mat)

OUTPUT:
              x                              
    x 1.0000000 0.9386463 0.9270723 0.9109491
      0.9386463 1.0000000 0.9994380 0.9969515
      0.9270723 0.9994380 1.0000000 0.9989905
      0.9109491 0.9969515 0.9989905 1.0000000


mod<-glm(class~.,data=dat,family=binomial()) #model

vif(mod) #massively high

OUTPUT:
x         V2         V3         V4 
319.573 204655.833 415308.187  45042.675
```

**UPDATE:**

I reached out to Dr. Harrell, the author of Hmisc package in R (and others) and he responded that as long as the algorithm converges (e.g. the logistic regression) and the standard errors have not exploded (as Maarten said below) - and the model fits well, best shown on a test set, then there is no issue with this collinearity.

Further, he stated (and this is present on page 65 of his excellent Regression Modeling Strategies [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441929185)) that collinearity between variables constructed in an algebraic fashion like restricted cubic splines is not an issue as multicollinearity only matters when that collinearity changes from sample to sample.

Comment: You can always orthogonalize the generated splines (for example the `rcsgen` Stata command uses Gram-Schmidt orthogonalizaton)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The multicollinearity can lead to numerical problems when estimating such a function. This is why some use [B-splines](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/nhli/r.newson/papers/sensparm.pdf) (or variations on that theme) instead of restricted cubic splines. So, I tend to see restricted cubic splines as one potentially usefull tool in a larger toolbox.

Comment: Hi Maarten, when you say numerical problems do you refer to convergence or such? If the regression converged and appears to do well on a test set - do you conclude the situation is not a problem?

Comment: If there are numerical problems then lack of convergence is a likely (but not a necessary) consequence. Unrealistic coefficient estimates and/or unrealisticly high standard errors are other possible consequences.

Comment: Maarten that is only the case if you are using non-modern software.  Modern software uses things like the QR decomposition rendering this a non-problem.

Comment: Methods like QR decomposition helped a lot. However, you can still break modern software, it has just become harder to do so.

Comment: @FrankHarrell What do you recommend when even with millions of observations and six independent variables modeled with 5-knot splines, the standard errors for one of the splines are extremely high (and with alternating signs on large coefficients for consecutive knots)? I am studying your book but am not sure how to proceed in this situation.

Comment: That may not be a problem.  But if there is a numerical problem, the `scale=TRUE` argument to some of the fitting functions in the R `rms` package will standardize all columns before fitting and unstandardize coefficients after fitting in a way that the user doesn't need to account for.

Comment: Don't look at individiual coefficients and standard errors so much.  Look at the entire fitted curve.